# Get an array from node and fill an HTML dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, http

So I have a nodejs server that is housing an array of users (each has a name and token). On the app startup (using ionic), I want to get the user array and fill an html drop down menu. I will post all code if asked for it. (not posting it because it doesn't seem necessary).

How can I achieve that exactly? I know it'll take an $http.get() inside my ionicPlatform.ready() method. But I don't know exactly how to pass an array from node to angular from angular to html dropdown menu.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

```js
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        android: {
          senderID: "411587591993"
        },
        browser: {
            pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
        },
        ios: {
            alert: "true",
            badge: "true",
            sound: "true"
        },
        windows: {}
    });
      push.on('registration', function(data) {
          console.log(data.registrationId);
          $rootScope.devToken = data.registrationId;
      })
      push.on('notification', function(data) {
          if (data.additionalData.foreground) {
              alert(data.message);
          }
      })
      $scope.users = null;
      $http.get('http://192.168.1.2:8080').then(function(response) {
         $scope.users = response.data;
          console.log(users);
      });
  });
})
```

```html
<body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Push Notifications</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
          <div class="form1" ng-controller="myCtrl">
              <form class="form">
                <input type="text" class="fName" placeholder="First Name"ng-model="fName">
                  
                <input type="text" class="lName" placeholder="Last Name"ng-model="lName">
                  
                <input type="text" class="messageText" placeholder="Message" ng-model="messageText">
                
                <select ng-model="users">
                      <option value="">Select User to Notify</option>
                </select> 
                
                <button class="button" ng-click="submit()"><span>Submit</span></button>
              </form>      
          </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```